# TinyMCE Custom Bullet List

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

I'm using TinyMCE 4.8.2.
I'm trying to add custom Bullets to the existing Bullet List dropdown in the editor.  I've done some searching and the answers I'm finding seem to apply to older versions of TinyMCE. When I implement them, nothing happens.

I would like to add items similar to Checkmarks, Arrows, Stars, etc, to the available Bullets.

Thank you for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found is to override the "style formats" button to add a class on the "ul" tags, see the tinymce doc : 
https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-formatting/#formats
the following article helped me a lot (for wordpress but helps to understand the logic)
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/128931/tinymce-adding-css-to-format-dropdown/128950
and because of the overload, it is necessary to restore the old styles, if you want. We can therefore add as many different classes as we want, then we process the class in css to customize the lists.

```
.custom-ul-class-caret li:before {
content:"";
font-family: FontAwesome;
display: inline;
margin-right: 10px;
```

}

my code for wordpress

```
    function my_tiny_mce_before_init( $mceInit) {
    $style_formats = array(
        array(
            "Title" =>"Headers",
                "items" => array(
                    array(
                        "Title" =>"Header 1",
                        "format" =>"h1',
                        "icon" =>"bold
                    ),
                    array(
                        "Title" =>"Header 2",
                        "format" =>"h2',
                        "icon" =>"bold
                    ),
                    array(
                        "Title" =>"Header 3",
                        "format" =>"h3",
                        "icon" =>"bold
                    ),
                    array(
                        "Title" =>"Header 4",
                        "format" =>"h4',
                        "icon" =>"bold
                    ),
                    array(
                        "Title" =>"Header 5",
                        "format" =>"h5',
                        "icon" =>"bold
                    ),
                    array(
                        "Title" =>"Header 6",
                        "format" =>"h6',
                        "icon" =>"bold
                    )
                )
        ),
        array(
            "title" =>"Inline",
                "items" => array(
                    array(
                        "title" =>"Bold",
                        "format" =>"bold",
                        "icon" =>"bold
                    ),
                    array(
                        "title" =>"Italic",
                        "format" =>"italic",
                        "icon" =>"italic
                    ),
                    array(
                        "Title" =>"Underline",
                        "format" =>"h3",
                        "icon" =>"underline
                    ),
                    array(
                        "Title" =>"Strikethrough",
                        "format" =>"strikethrough",
                        "icon" =>"strikethrough
                    ),
                    array(
                        "title" =>"Superscript",
                        "format" =>"Superscript",
                        "icon" =>"Superscript
                    ),
                    array(
                        "title" =>"Subscript",
                        "format" => "Subscript",
                        "icon" =>"Subscript
                    ),
                    array(
                        "title" =>"Code",
                        "format" =>"code",
                        "icon" =>"code
                    )
                )
        ),
        array(
            "Title" =>"Blocks",
                "items" => array(
                    array(
                        "title" =>"Paragraph",
                        "format" =>"p',
                    ),
                    array(
                        "Title" =>"Blockquote",
                        "format" => "blockquote",
                    ),
                    array(
                        "title" =>"Div',
                        "format" =>"div",
                    ),
                    array(
                        "title" =>"Pre",
                        "format" =>"pre",
                    )
                )
        ),
        array(
            "title" => "Bulleted list",
                "items" => array(
                    array(
                        "title" =>"caret", // Title to show in dropdown
                        "selector" =>"ul', // Element to add class to
                        "classes" => "custom-ul-class-caret" // CSS class to add
                    ),
                )
        )
    );
    $mceInit['style_formats'] = json_encode( $style_formats);   
    return $mceInit;    
}
add_filter("tiny_mce_before_init','my_tiny_mce_before_init');
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question, it should be posted as a comment.

Comment: the answer is modified ;)